# Can you give an example of an electrolytic process that has high Faraday efficiency but low energy effiency

Tags: electrochemistry, energy

I want a nice example to help illustrate the conceptual difference between these terms to a biologist.

I found this figure which might be helpful.https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343879093_SAPHYS_Project_-*Development_and_Testing_of_a_Stand-Alone_Photovoltaic_HYdrogen_energy_System*-_Final_Report

[image]

Could I give an example of a biological system that perfect transfers electrons between different donor/acceptors where the initial donor has high redox potential and the terminal acceptor has low redox potential. Then there is 100% Faradaic effeciency, but low energy efficiency.

Thank your for your support.